# how to exclude method if compilation symbol is not set? how to pass variable number of parameters and format them in function body?

Tags: c++

I wrote my own simple class for logging. I understand that I better to use some kind of library (boost.log, log4cpp?) but let's anyway discuss my simple class:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"


Logger::Logger(std::string fileName)
{
    logFile.open(fileName);
}


Logger::~Logger(void)
{
    logFile.close();
}


void Logger::Error(std::string message) {
    logFile << message << std::endl;
}

void Logger::Debug(std::string message) {
    logFile << message << std::endl;
}
```

1. I want my methods to accept variable number of arguments, so I can pass parameters like that `"Error code: %x", code`. How to do that?
2. I want `Debug` method to be excluded if `LOG_DEBUG` compilation symbol is not set. in C# I can just add `[Conditional("LOG_DEBUG")]` before the method declaration, but now to do that in c++?

**upd** Regarding 1 i've tried that and it works:

```
void Logger::Debug(std::string message, ...) {
va_list arglist;
fprintf(pFile, message.c_str(), arglist);
```

Comment: following two should help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506632/c-conditional-compilation

Comment: @Caribou sorry i'm just starting learning c++

Comment: @javapowered no need to be sorry (I didn't dv this btw) Joachims answer is a good start. You could extend the Macros and add more params

Comment: @Caribou I need some easy way to exclude at all any logging at Release build but to keep it in Debug build. I even don't want to have any "extra comparision" i really want compiler to just exclude logging cause I care about latency in Release build.

Comment: @javapowered thats exactly what you can achieve with Joachims answer - if you have a test for Debug (or a #define of your choice) - if true then define as below, if not define LOG_DEBUG(logger, output) as empty - look up the preprocessor on google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want my methods to accept variable number of arguments, so I can pass parameters like that "Error code: %x", code. How to do that?

You have two solutions for this:

1. use printf-like formatting. This would require the usage of va_list, va_arg and va_end macros.
2. use operator overloading (as in @Joachim's answer).

> I want Debug method to be excluded if LOG_DEBUG compilation symbol is not set. in C# I can just add [Conditional("LOG_DEBUG")] before the method declaration, but now to do that in c++?

You define a logging macro, in two different ways, depending on DEBUG macro definition (or NDEBUG or something similar):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define LOGE(X) Logger::Error(X)
#define LOGD(X) Logger::Debug(X)
#else
#define LOGE(X) 
#define LOGD(X) 
#endif
```

Comment: probaly I can just forward "..." arguments to some function `sprintf`? that can automatically use them...

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way, in my opinion, is to use macros for this:

```
#define LOG_DEBUG(logger, output) \
    do { logger.getStream() << "DEBUG: " << output << std::endl; } while (0)

LOG_DEBUG(logger, "Some value = " << some_value);
```

This will allow you to use all the normal C++ stream manipulators.

---

As for the second part, it's simple preprocessor trickery too:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# define LOG_DEBUG(logger, output) do { ... } while (0)
#else
# define LOG_DEBUG(logger, output)
#endif
```